# Tool for (programming language) benchmarks

Tags: performance, shell, programming-languages, benchmarking

The [Computer Language
Benchmarks Game](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org) compares the speed of a selection of algorithms in different programming languages. It does not include less popular languages, e.g. Perl 6.

Is there an easy-to-use tool (beyond `time` and preferably with some visualizations) for creating my own benchmarks of scripts in different languages?

Comment: What problem are you having with `time` that you would like a tool to solve for you?  Do you want a more accurate picture of CPU / memory utilization, so you can tell when a language takes advantage of / uses time on multiple CPU cores to get a result faster?  Or peak memory footprint?  `/usr/bin/time` shows `maxresident` memory in kiB, and minor/major pagefaults.  `perf` can give you HW performance counters under Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this but thought it looked interesting -- https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine

Answer (score 0):

[hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) was inspired by [bench](https://github.com/Gabriel439/bench), which *can* generate visualizations if you want.

Answer (score -1):

For some definition of *easy-to-use* -- you could use the same scripts as the benchmarks game.

The Python measurement scripts -- [https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/download/benchmarksgame-script.zip](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/download/benchmarksgame-script.zip)

Source code for the current programs -- [https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/download/benchmarksgame-sourcecode.zip](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/download/benchmarksgame-sourcecode.zip)

---

That's [what the "Python Interpreters Benchmarks" guy does](https://pybenchmarks.org/).